# Bold text in Flutter bulleted list

Tags: flutter-layout

I have a page with a bulleted list. I'd like 3 of the list-items to contain some bold text. Not paragraphs that are all bold text, but paragraphs that contain 1 or 2 words in bold. For example,

- I would like just **this** text to be bold.
- In this second bulleted paragraph, I want **these words** to be bold.
- In this third bulleted paragraph, **I want these words** in bold.

I'd really appreciate help. Here's my code:

```
import 'package:cordova/ui/contact/contact.dart';
import 'package:cordova/ui/home.dart';
import 'package:cordova/ui/information/license_page.dart';
import 'package:cordova/ui/widget/contact_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_windowmanager/flutter_windowmanager.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';

class NotesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  NotesScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NotesScreenState createState() => _NotesScreenState();
}

class _NotesScreenState extends State<NotesScreen> {
  disableScreen() async {
    await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
  }

  Text bold(String abc) {
    return Text(abc,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 35,
            fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    disableScreen();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          height: 50,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()),
                    (route) => false);
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.home,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 25,
              )),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          color: HexColor('#ffffff'),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: HexColor('#008AD8')),
                //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        TextButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            label: const Text(
                              "Back",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            )),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => ContactScreen()));
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.mail,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 25,
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Information',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
                           Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          const UnorderedListItemBold(
                              "I would like just ", "this", "text to be bold."),
                          const UnorderedListItemBold(
                              "In this second bulleted paragraph, I want ",
                              "these words",
                              "to be bold."),
                          const UnorderedListItemBold(
                              "In this third bulleted paragraph, ",
                              "I want these words",
                              "in bold."),
                          UnorderedList(const [
                            "This paragraph has NO bold text.",
                            "Neither does this one.",
                            "And this paragraph is also plain text."
                          ]),
                        ],
                      ))),
                            Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          UnorderedList(const [
                            "More text, plain and simple.",
                            "And more text in another paragraph, plain and simple.",
                            "Another paragraph of plain text.",
                            "A final short paragraph in this section."
                          ]),
                        ],
                      ))),
                            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                    child: const Text(
                      "Final paragraph of this page, just plain text.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        )));
  }
}

class UnorderedList extends StatelessWidget {
  UnorderedList(this.texts);
  final List<String> texts;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var widgetList = <Widget>[];
    for (var text in texts) {
      // Add list item
      widgetList.add(UnorderedListItem(text));
      // Add space between items
      widgetList.add(SizedBox(height: 5.0));
    }

    return Column(children: widgetList);
  }
}

class UnorderedListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const UnorderedListItem(this.text);
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("• ",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 35,
              fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
            )),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
              )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class UnorderedListItemBold extends StatelessWidget {
  const UnorderedListItemBold(this.text, this.bold, this.remaining);
  final String text;
  final String bold;
  final String remaining;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("• ",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 35,
              fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
            )),
        Expanded(
            child: RichText(
          text: const TextSpan(
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay', color: Colors.black),
            children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(text: 'I would like just '),
              TextSpan(
                  text: 'this ', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              TextSpan(text: 'text to be bold.'),
            ],
            child: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(text: 'In this second bulleted paragraph, I want '),
              TextSpan(
                  text: 'these words ',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              TextSpan(text: 'to be bold.'),
            ],
            children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(text: 'In this third bulleted paragraph,  '),
              TextSpan(
                  text: 'I want these words ',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              TextSpan(text: 'in bold.'),
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to achieve can be seen in the attached image - specifically in the 3 sentences "Lorem ipsum hoorah!", where the "ipsum" is in bold.[image]

Here's a solution:

```
class NotesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  NotesScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NotesScreenState createState() => _NotesScreenState();
}

class _NotesScreenState extends State<NotesScreen> {
  // disableScreen() async {
  //   await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
  // }

  // Text bold(String abc) {
  //   return Text(abc,
  //       style: TextStyle(
  //           fontSize: 35,
  //           fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
  //           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
  // }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    // disableScreen();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          height: 50,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                //     context,
                //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()),
                //         (route) => false);
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.home,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 25,
              )),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              color: Color(0xFFffffff),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFFE30613)),
                    //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            TextButton.icon(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                },
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                label: const Text(
                                  "Back",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                )),
                            IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // Navigator.push(
                                  //     context,
                                  //     MaterialPageRoute(
                                  //         builder: (context) => ContactScreen()));
                                },
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.mail,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 25,
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Information',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 30,
                                fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                        child: const Text(
                          "Lorem ipsum sweetness and light.",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: const Text(
                        'Lorem',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                        child: const Text(
                          "Lorem ipsum.",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: const Text(
                        'Lorem',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              const UnorderedListItemBold(
                                  text: "Lorem",
                                  bold: "ipsum",
                                  remaining: "summa cum laude."),
                              const UnorderedListItemBold(
                                  text: "Lorem",
                                  bold:"ipsum2",
                                  remaining: "summa cum laude."),
                              const UnorderedListItemBold(
                                  text: "Lorem",
                                  bold:"ipsum3",
                                  remaining: "summa cum laude."),
                              UnorderedList(const [
                                "Lorem ipsum",
                                "Lorem ipsum",
                                "Lorem ipsum"
                              ]),
                            ],
                          ))),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: const Text(
                        'Lorem',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                        child: const Text(
                          "Lorem ipsum",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              UnorderedList(const [
                                "Lorem ipsum",
                                "and more lorem ipsum",
                                "and more lorem ipsum",
                                "and more lorem ipsum"
                              ]),
                            ],
                          ))),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: const Text(
                        'Lorem',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                        child: const Text(
                          "Lorem ipsum",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: const Text(
                        'Lorem',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                        child: const Text(
                          "Lorem ipsum",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            )));
  }
}

class UnorderedList extends StatelessWidget {
  UnorderedList(this.texts);
  final List<String> texts;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var widgetList = <Widget>[];
    for (var text in texts) {
      // Add list item
      widgetList.add(UnorderedListItem(text));
      // Add space between items
      widgetList.add(SizedBox(height: 5.0));
    }

    return Column(children: widgetList);
  }
}

class UnorderedListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const UnorderedListItem(this.text);
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("• ",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 35,
              fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
            )),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
              )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


class UnorderedListItemBold extends StatelessWidget {

  final String text;
  final String bold;
  final String remaining;
  const UnorderedListItemBold({ Key? key, required this.text, required this.bold,  required this.remaining }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("• ",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 35,
              fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay',
            )),
        Expanded(
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'RedHatDisplay', color: Colors.black),
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(text: text),
                  TextSpan(
                      text: bold,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  TextSpan(
                      text:
                      remaining),
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this will be of use to someone else in the future. :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).